# При изменении свойства элемента через триггер, не срабатывает привязка

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть элемент, используемый в шаблоне DataGrid,  со свойством IsSelected,  привязанным к одноименному свойству объекта.

```
//Расширенный Лэйбл
//XAML
<Label x:Class="Solution.XLabel"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             x:Name="Parent">
</Label>

//code behind
partial class XLabel
{
    public XLabel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value);}
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsSelected", typeof (bool), typeof (XLabel), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(bool)));
}     

//XAML
<DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate" DataType="data:DataRowView">
    <local:XLabel x:Name="Label" Content="{Binding Path=Title}"
                  Background="{Binding Path=BackColor}"
                  IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                       AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}, 
                                       Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Label" Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>


//Объект привязки
class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isSelected;

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return this._isSelected; }
        set
        {
            this._isSelected = value; //при срабатывании триггера не меняется
            _OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }
}
```

Если менять свойство элемента через триггер, то привязка к объекту не срабатывает, т.е. свойство объекта не изменяется.
Как заставить работать привязку в таком случае?

Comment: Похоже, у вас везде односторонняя привязка. Попробуйте использовать Mode=TwoWay везде, где выполняется привязка к свойству IsSelected

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev все равно не работает.

Comment: У вас `XLabel` определено _именно так_?

Comment: @VladD сделал пример еще более приближенным к реальному коду

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непосредственная проблема заключается в том, что у вас есть на `IsSelected` есть два источника значения: локально установленный `{Binding Path=IsSelected}`, и установленный через триггер. Поэтому выставленное через триггер значение не существует «одновременно» с привязкой (binding), а замещает его. Поэтому и значение не пропагируется назад, в `DataContext`.

---

С более широкой точки зрения, проблема состоит в том, что вы хотите управлять логикой программы на уровне View, а не на уровне ViewModel. Вы стараетесь направить данные «вниз», и организовать на этом сложную логику. Это не является рекомендованным, поддерживаемым паттерном, поэтому на этом пути у вас всегда будут возникать сложности.

Правильный подход такой. Давайте-ка сделаем так, чтобы логика «выделен объект или нет» разруливалась на уровне View Model'и:

```
class Data : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    private bool _isParentSelected;
    public bool IsParentSelected
    {
        get { return _isParentSelected; }
        set { _isParentSelected = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

class ParentData : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            if (First != null)
                First.IsParentSelected = value;
            if (Second != null)
                Second.IsParentSelected = value;
        }
    }

    public Data First { get; set; }
    public Data Second { get; set; }
}
```

Отлично, теперь бизнес-логика реализована на уровне бизнес-логики, и можно нацепить сверху View:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="..." AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <!-- связываем свойство IsSelected в VM и View -->
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="First">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ParentData}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding First.Title}" Name="tb"/>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="tb" Value="Yellow"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Second">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ParentData}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Second.Title}" Name="tb"/>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="tb" Value="Green"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Обратите внимание, что нестандартные контролы оказались не нужны, всё покрывается `DataTemplate`'ами.

Comment: Возможно Вы неправильно поняли. При срабатывании триггера, значение свойства элемента меняется, но не меняется значение свойства объекта, к которому он привязан.
Ставил эксперименты с просты `TextBox`, так как на тексте наглядней.
Когда срабатывает триггер, свойство `Text` у `TextBox` меняет значение, а у объекта, к которому привязан `TextBox` - нет. Экспериментировал с `UpdateSourceTrigger` и пр., результат тот же.

Comment: @xlmax: А, понял. Ну а на что вы рассчитываете? У вас была привязка (`IsSelected="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"`). Вы её заменили на непосредственное значение (`Property="IsSelected" Value="True"`), «отменив» при этом привязку. С этого момента привязка больше, понятно, не действует.

Comment: @xlmax: Из двух значений `IsSelected` действует ровно одно. Вы предполагали, что система увидит, что источников значений много, найдёт в этом логику, и разрулит это в рантайме? Если так, что было бы делать системе, если два `Binding`'а пытаются выставить разные значения?

Comment: @ VladD: теперь я понял, что происходит. Спасибо Вам! Буду думать как решить проблему. Если подскажите, буду признателен)

Comment: @xlmax: Попробую подсказать, но для этого нужна более широкая картина: какую логику более высокого уровня вы хотите реализовать?

Comment: Нужно было выделить один и тот же объект в разных представлениях. Одно из них - DataGrid, каждой я ячейке которого соответствует объект модели.

Comment: @xlmax: То есть у вас один и тот же `Data`-объект показывается в нескольких местах, и вы хотите через `IsSelected` подсветить его одновременно в каждом из вхождений?

Comment: Да, так и есть. Это упрощенно конечно. Что касается DataGrid, то несколько подобных объектов будут принадлежать объекту - родителю и занимать несколько ячеек. При выделении одного из них, аналогично нужно показать выделение других (с тем же родителем).

Comment: @xlmax: Окей, понял. Сейчас подумаю.

Comment: @xlmax: Окей, первая мысль — вы не можете использовать для вашей цели триггеры, т. к. они устанавливают «альтернативное» значение для свойства. Попробую выразить вашу семантику через просто Binding.

Comment: @xlmax: Обновил ответ. Если нужен полный код — [здесь](http://pastebin.com/n4RdfuNt).